# Unable to delete file whose name starts with "sed"

Tags: 18.04, permissions, nautilus, security, malware

I noticed this file on my desktop "sedxzNQQm", but it does not display in Nautilus from the Desktop directory. Furthermore, when I try to delete the file I get the following error. What is the best way to clean up my machine and get rid of this virus/malware, if that's what it is?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 with the latest updates/patches applied.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not a virus/malware

Comment: When working in-place (`-i`), [a program called `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) create temporary [files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835035/4970442).

Answer (score 1):

There is a small lock in the right upper corner of this file. This means that the current user does not have permissions to delete/modify the file.

You can delete this file with sudo:

open a terminal and type:

```
sudo rm /home/bbudd/Desktop/sedxzNQQm
```

Comment: This is a way to get rid of the file, but first OP should understand wherefrom this file comes. It's name refers it may be some temporary file. If it is not  created with user permissions, it may refer, that you have run something with sudo (and directly from Desktop).

Comment: As @PabloBianchi commented he maybe ran a [sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833518/why-does-sed-leave-many-files-around/9835035#9835035) with sudo or another user on his Desktop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I ran the sudo rm command suggested and received the same error as depicted above. This is why I am puzzled, what type of file can be visible or virtually located on the desktop, but not physically exist anywhere on the file system?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the command and the result in terminal?